# c# - what is the efficient way to split string to 2 arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

i have a string  like `"1,2,3,4,5,6,7"`.

always 7 numbers !  seperated by `,`

what is the best way to split it into 2 arrays of integers ,

the firts array contain 1-5 numbers

the second array contain 6-7 numbers

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var numString = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
var numArray = numString.Split(',');
var array1 = numArray.Take(5).ToArray();
var array2 = numArray.Skip(5).ToArray();
```

or if you want an array of `int`s.

```
var numString = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
var numArray = numString.Split(',');
var array1 = numArray.Take(5).Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
var array2 = numArray.Skip(5).Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

Note that you can skip `.ToArray()` if you don't require an array.

**Edit:**
Actually, the fastest code I can come up with is

```
var numString = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
var numArray = numString.Split(',');

var array1 = new int[5];
var array2 = new int[2];

array1[0] = int.Parse(numArray[0]);
array1[1] = int.Parse(numArray[1]);
array1[2] = int.Parse(numArray[2]);
array1[3] = int.Parse(numArray[3]);
array1[4] = int.Parse(numArray[4]);
array2[0] = int.Parse(numArray[5]);
array2[1] = int.Parse(numArray[6]);
```

It is approximately 60% faster than the first version.
I compared the speed of Jason's version, with and without ToArray after the Select, both are 15-20% slower.
The first because `int.Parse()` is called 12 times instead of 7, the second because the extra `.ToArray()`.

Here is my benchmark code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Stackoverflow_Test
{
    class TestToArrayVsEnumerator
    {
        private const string numString = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
        private readonly string[] numArray;
        private const int iterations = 100000;
        private const int numTests = 10;

        public TestToArrayVsEnumerator()
        {
            numArray = numString.Split(',');
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest;
            Console.WriteLine("Warmup");
            RunTest(WithEnumerator);
            RunTest(WithSelectFirst);
            RunTest(WithSelectToArray);
            RunTest(StraightForward);

            Console.WriteLine("--- test start ---");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var t in Enumerable.Range(0, numTests))
            {
                var timeEnumerator = RunTest(WithEnumerator);
                var timeWithSelectFirst = RunTest(WithSelectFirst);
                var timeWithSelectToArray = RunTest(WithSelectToArray);
                var timeStraightForward = RunTest(StraightForward);

                sb.AppendLine("WithEnumerator, " + timeEnumerator.TotalMilliseconds + " ms. "
                    + "WithSelectFirst, " + timeWithSelectFirst.TotalMilliseconds + " ms. (" + ((100 * ((double)timeWithSelectFirst.Ticks / (double)timeEnumerator.Ticks)) - 100) + "%) "
                    + "WithSelectToArray, " + timeWithSelectToArray.TotalMilliseconds + " ms. (" + ((100 * ((double)timeWithSelectToArray.Ticks / (double)timeEnumerator.Ticks)) - 100) + "%) "
                    + "StraightForward, " + timeStraightForward.TotalMilliseconds + " ms. (" + ((100 * ((double)timeStraightForward.Ticks / (double)timeEnumerator.Ticks)) - 100) + "%) "
                    );
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("--- test end ---");
        }

        private TimeSpan RunTest(Action test)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, iterations))
            {
                test();
            }
            sw.Stop();
            return sw.Elapsed;
        }

        public void WithEnumerator()
        {
            var array1 = numArray.Take(5).Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
            var array2 = numArray.Skip(5).Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
        }

        public void WithSelectFirst()
        {
            var intArray = numArray.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
            var array1 = numArray.Take(5).ToArray();
            var array2 = numArray.Skip(5).ToArray();
        }

        public void WithSelectToArray()
        {
            var intArray = numArray.Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
            var array1 = numArray.Take(5).ToArray();
            var array2 = numArray.Skip(5).ToArray();
        }

        public void StraightForward()
        {
            var array1 = new int[5];
            var array2 = new int[2];

            array1[0] = int.Parse(numArray[0]);
            array1[1] = int.Parse(numArray[1]);
            array1[2] = int.Parse(numArray[2]);
            array1[3] = int.Parse(numArray[3]);
            array1[4] = int.Parse(numArray[4]);
            array2[0] = int.Parse(numArray[5]);
            array2[1] = int.Parse(numArray[6]);
        }
    }
}
```

with the result (release code, start with no debugging)

```
WithEnumerator, 446,3176 ms. WithSelectFirst, 538,4354 ms. (20,639517688749%)  WithSelectToArray, 505,5178 ms. (13,2641419473487%) StraightForward, 178,6037 ms. (-59,9828238904314%)     
WithEnumerator, 445,463 ms.  WithSelectFirst, 528,0676 ms. (18,5435378471388%) WithSelectToArray, 525,6011 ms. (17,9898442743842%) StraightForward, 181,1559 ms. (-59,3331208203599%)     
WithEnumerator, 454,5901 ms. WithSelectFirst, 526,0643 ms. (15,722779708577%)  WithSelectToArray, 524,5135 ms. (15,3816372155927%) StraightForward, 185,8895 ms. (-59,1083263801829%)     
WithEnumerator, 442,4805 ms. WithSelectFirst, 525,8961 ms. (18,8518138087441%) WithSelectToArray, 558,0706 ms. (26,1232076893784%) StraightForward, 208,8639 ms. (-52,7970385135616%)     
WithEnumerator, 454,3597 ms. WithSelectFirst, 528,4238 ms. (16,3007634699997%) WithSelectToArray, 531,6279 ms. (17,0059536530198%) StraightForward, 185,5925 ms. (-59,1529574475905%)     
WithEnumerator, 452,76 ms.   WithSelectFirst, 542,3876 ms. (19,7958300203198%) WithSelectToArray, 553,0012 ms. (22,1400300379892%) StraightForward, 184,5231 ms. (-59,2448316989133%)     
WithEnumerator, 468,6732 ms. WithSelectFirst, 528,5409 ms. (12,7738688706758%) WithSelectToArray, 549,7821 ms. (17,3060674260871%) StraightForward, 188,0931 ms. (-59,8668965923377%)     
WithEnumerator, 489,7136 ms. WithSelectFirst, 560,0267 ms. (14,3580043519314%) WithSelectToArray, 556,3374 ms. (13,6046456541129%) StraightForward, 177,8818 ms. (-63,6763610404122%)     
WithEnumerator, 462,5361 ms. WithSelectFirst, 552,7817 ms. (19,5110392464502%) WithSelectToArray, 548,7365 ms. (18,6364696723131%) StraightForward, 180,1382 ms. (-61,054239874466%)     
WithEnumerator, 462,787 ms.  WithSelectFirst, 536,089 ms.  (15,8392521829697%) WithSelectToArray, 543,2204 ms. (17,3802202741218%) StraightForward, 180,4709 ms. (-61,0034637965198%)
```

Comment: Generalized to `.Take(n)` and `.Skip(array.Length - n)`

Comment: @Esteban Araya: Huh? Why wouldn't it be `Take(n)` and `Skip(n)`?

Comment: each of `numArray.Take(5).Select(s => int.Parse(s))` traverse array 2 times, which is not efficient way.

Comment: @Saeed, what part do you mean traverse 2 times? You might like to move  int.Parse to the numArray, but then you need to do .ToArray() on that part too (which is not very efficient). The expensive part in the query is the int.Parse. My code runs int.Parse 7 times (if you skip either array1 or array2 based on some condition you will get 2 or 5. Jason's code executes int.Parse 12 times (put a breakpoint and see).

Comment: Take(5) is a first traverse and Select(s => int.Parse(s)) is a second one. but if Jason adds ToArray in first and remove other ToArrays there is 7 time int.Parse, and traverse list (near) 4 time, but your approach (if you remove extra toarray) traverse list near 5 time.

Comment: @Saeed, Jason's code might be shorter to type, but it ain't faster to execute. Have a look at the updated answer with benchmark.

Answer (score 4):

```
string someString = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
var numbers = someString.Split(',')
                         .Select(s => Int32.Parse(s));
int[] firstFive = numbers.Take(5).ToArray();
int[] afterFirstFive = numbers.Skip(5).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1, Your way is better than others, but for small size array it's better to not using linq, It's very slower than normal `for`.

Comment: @Saeed For such a small array, I don't think performance is an issue at all. Unless this is the core of your application running 1,000,000,000 times a second, it shouldn't matter when compared to anything else.

Answer (score 2):

```
var n = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7".Split(',');
var first5 = n.Take(5).ToArray();
var last2 = n.Skip(5).ToArray();
```

If you want to convert them to integers, you could do something like this:

```
  string x = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7";
  var f = x.Split(',').Take(5).Select(s => { int v; if (!Int32.TryParse(s, out v)) v = -1; return v; });
  var g = x.Split(',').Skip(5).Select(s => { int v; if (!Int32.TryParse(s, out v)) v = -1; return v; });
```